# Codeigniter return values after ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Firstly sorry, I'm a really big beginner.

I ran into a problem that I can't really solve, i am building a facebook-like wall. and after the post is sent, I would like the results to append to a div, but I'm totally lost.

The problem is that it sends perfectly, but not shows the results

Here is my code

html

```
<?php foreach($stream_posts as $sp): ?>
    <div id="sp_<?php echo $sp->sid; ?>" class="row stream-posts">
        <div class="span1 stream-thumb">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt="">
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>  
        <div class="span5 stream-content">
            <a href="#" class="author"><?php echo $sp->first_name ." ". $sp->last_name; ?></a>
            <p>
                <?php echo nl2br($sp->text); ?>
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

jQuery

```
$('.stream-form').on('submit', function(){
        var streamData = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>stream/insert_stream",
            type: "POST",
            data: streamData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(stream) {

                if(stream.error == 0)
                {
                    $('.stream-text').val("");
                    $('.stream-posts').append().text(stream.text);


                }   
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

In this jQuery code it appends all of it and breaks the div, i would like to show the new post what was submitted

Model

```
    function add_stream()
    {

        $data = array(
            'added_by' => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'text' => $this->input->post('stream_text')
        );

        $this->db->insert('pf_stream', $data);


    }

function load_stream_post()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('pf_stream');
        $this->db->join('pf_users', 'pf_users.id = pf_stream.added_by');
        $this->db->order_by('pf_stream.sid', 'DESC');
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {   
            foreach($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $sdata[] = $row;
            }
        return $sdata;  
        }

}
    // this is for the view
    function select_stream()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('pf_stream');
        $this->db->join('pf_users', 'pf_users.id = pf_stream.added_by');
        $this->db->order_by('pf_stream.sid', 'DESC');
        $this->db->limit(5);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        {   
            foreach($query->result() as $row)
            {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        return $data;   
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
 public function index()
   {
        $this->load->view('partials/header');
        $data['stream_posts'] = $this->stream_model->select_stream();
           $this->load->view('stream_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('partials/footer');
   }

    function insert_stream()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('stream_text', 'Üzenet', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == false)
        {
            $stream = array('error' => 1);
        } else {
            $this->stream_model->add_stream();
            $data['stream_result'] = $this->stream_model->load_stream_post();
            $stream = array(
               'error' => 0, 
               'sid' => $data['stream_result'][0]->sid,
               'text' => $data['stream_result'][0]->text,
               'author' => $data['stream_result'][0]->first_name . " " . $data['stream_result'][0]->last_name,
            );
        }
        echo json_encode($stream);
    }
```

Could someone please give me a hint what am I missing?

Comment: Long question for me .. what is ur firebug console says ? return results correctly ?

Comment: if i console log the results returns all okay, but im lost at the append part

Comment: `.append` and `.prepend` ,have a parm .. pls check Sheikh Heera answer..ur are appening nothing but setting the text...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is, here

```
$('.stream-posts').append().text(stream.text);
```

This should be

```
$('.stream-posts').append(stream.text);
```

Comment: @Side, the `.stream-posts` divs (rows) are built inside a php `foreach` loop, meaning there can be many of them. `$('.stream-posts').append(stream.text);` will append to **all** of them. Is that what you want?